# Get element in form ngFor Angular2 With checkbox

Tags: angular

I am trying get an element in my Angular2.

The problem is that I get true but I should be the ID the my element ->

HTML

```xml
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of params">
                <td class="left">{{data.name}}</td>
                <td class="left">"{{data.surname}}"</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="toggle-switch" >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{data.id}}" [value]="data.id" name="{{data.id}}" [(ngModel)]="selectParam">
                    <label for="{{data.id}}"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```js
  public params: Object;
  public selectParam: string ;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  private fetchData() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/get';
    this.service.get(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.params = data;
      }
    );
  }

  public save() {
    console.log( "id" , this.selectParam);
  }
```

Here, I link "selectParam" with NgModel from checkbox and I get `[value]="data.id"` But I don't get ID in my console.log I get True or false...

Comment: Why don't you use an event handler e.g. `(click)="onClicked(data.id)"`?

Comment: because I should send form with submit.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. If you want to submit the whole form you can do that e.g. with an explicit button but what do the checkboxes have to do with that?

Comment: Except you want to submit each of those `data` elements one by one - in that case I think you'd have to wrap your fields in extra forms s.t. you can submit them one by one.

Comment: because is NgFor I have 4 ó 20 elements ... then 1,2.. or 20 elements are true, I need know only elements with true for send his Id

Comment: try to use Angular reactive forms, since this approach is better for your task.

Comment: no, no I don't need check nothing, I use check for change true or false in my Server when I send this data (true or false) with his ID to Server

Answer (score 0):

Value for checkbox is always true or false

You need to change

```
public selectParam: string; => public selectParam: string[];
```

and then use:

```
(click)="checkboxStateChanged($event, data.id)"
```

where

```
checkboxStateChanged($event, id){
    if($event){
        this.selectParam.push(id)
    }else{
        this.selectParam = this.selectParam.filter(x => x != id)
    }
}
```

you will have all items changed to true in selectParam

Comment: I have NgFor  with 4 or 20 elements ... then 1,2.. or 20 elements are true, I need know only elements with true for send his Id . With your code only check 1 element, I don't need check notthing... I need send the elements with check a true to Server.

Comment: do you want to send it by clicking something? how elements become true?

Comment: I have a button submit, I want send all Elements that changed to Server, but when The user does click in button "send"